# CSS aligning boxes next to each other

Tags: css, wordpress, wpbakery

I'm trying to do some changes in wordpress (wpbakery) with some css styling. However I'm not getting the results I expect.

I'm simply trying to show some boxes with text, like below:

```
<div style="float: left;">Test</div>
<div style="float: left;">This is a longer test. This is a longer test. This is a longer test.</div>
```

I would expect the two boxes to flow next to each other. But if the text in the second box is two long, the boxes goes to the next line.

I have recreated the problem with:

```
 <div style="margin: auto; width: 200px;">
 <div style="float: left;">Test</div>
 <div style="float: left;">This is a longer test. This is a longer test. This is a longer test.</div>
 </div>
```

Is there a way to fix this? Setting the width is not an option for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using float:left, you can use: "display:inline-block", this will put the div next to each other. I'll also recommend you to put some padding on each side of the divs.

You can see your working code here, this is the most cleanest way I found:

```css
.nextto{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
 <div class="nextto">Test</div>
 <div class="nextto">This is a longer test. This is a longer test. This is a longer test.</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I still get the same result when using inline-block

Comment: Check the code I shared now please. Using inline-block will help you with responsiveness too because you will be able to assign a width, instead of display:inline;
Please also check your code and put a 100% width, since you are using a fixed with on main container.

Comment: Looks better. I know I might not initial wrote about it, but my first box should be 50px and the second should take of the rest of the space. Possible?

Comment: It would not be the best in terms of responsive guidelines, but you can put a class nexxtofirst and add the max-width:50px and then another one for the second box playing with the % of the width.

Please vote my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You should read up on [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It will make your life easier: 
In flexbox it would be like

```
.main-container: {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
```

Comment: Seems to work - however I have an image that resizes depending on how much text I have in the second box. A way to fix that first box?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use flexboxes

```
 <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between">
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>This is a longer test. This is a longer test. This is a longer test.</div>
 </div>
```

Inside child divs you can set width or flex-basis